# c# Silent install do localDB

Tags: c#, setup, sql-server-localdb

Meu programa precisa do SqlLocalDB.msi para rodar. Ja baixei esse arquivo e coloquei no CD que vou distribuir o programa. A dúvida é:

Existe algum jeito de fazer meu setup.exe executar esse SqlLocalDB.msi logo após terminar de instalar meu programa? Assim o cliente nao precisa abrir os arquivos do cd e executar o localDB.

Li sobre uma linha de comando que faz silent Install

```
msiexec /i SqlLocalDB.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES
```

aonde digita isso? Como faço esse silent install?

Answer (score 0):

Esse comando irá fazer a instalação de um pacote MSI sem nenhuma intervenção do usuário, o parâmetro /i indica ser uma instalação (/x desinstala, /f reisntala/repara), já o parametro /qn indica que não deve ser apresentada nenhuma interface (no UI) para o usuário.
Já o parâmetro IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES indica ao instalador do Sql para ele aceitar todos os termos de licença, evitando a pergunta ao usuário.

[Opções de linha de comando do msiexec](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/aa367988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)